# Username formatting for Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when creating a question or writing an answer to a question, I find myself typing in `@username` to indicate I'm referring to a specific user in my post. This however, does not automatically get translated into a link which would take you to the user's profile, if clicked on. Also, I assume this will not in any way notify the user of me mentioning them.

What's the recommended formatting to make such username link – and will the user get notified of me mentioning them?

This seems kind of cumbersome:

```
[fredrik](http://www.stackoverflow.com/users/2448495/fredrik)
```

EDIT: I agree it's probably not a good idea to have users getting a notification when mentioned in questions and answers. It was merely a question on my part. But I still think that there should be a simpler, faster way to link to a user.

Comment: Users aren't notified when mentioned except in comments if they have participated, or if they have edited the post. There isn't much of a reason to bother them in any other situation. You can give credit to an existing answer and linking to the user's profile is a great way to acknowledge them, but they don't need to be notified whenever this happens.

Comment: However, something like `[user:1835379]` being converted into an url like `[Cerbrus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus)` would be nice.

Comment: Let's not ahve automatic user profile links in comments, it would add a lot of noise for little benefit. What Cerbrus suggests sounds good though

Comment: This seems awfully ... social. Next thing you know, we'll be able to upvote and downvote user profiles ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I always link to someone's profile when referencing someone else's posts.